# What is the equivalent of rbga in hexadecimal?

Tags: php, colors, imagemagick

I have this code to color text and add transparency it

```
  $draw->setFillColor('rgba(0,0,255,0.5)');
```

It's working perfectly but I want to do the same thing with hex format.
How can I remplace `'rgba(0,0,255,0.5)` to `#0000FF` ... I don't know how can I add the transparency parameter.

Comment: Hex color codes with alpha values `#AARRGGBB` aren't supported in HTML.

Comment: @mario, Is there an other way to add transparency to my text?

Comment: Tith the `rgba(…)` syntax you already have, or with CSS `opacity:`

Comment: @mario, Ok thank a lot!

Comment: @mario, I don't believe this is duplicate. The OP is asking how ImageMagick parses color, specifically [parsing and querying color compliance](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/master/MagickCore/color.c#L2217). CSS & HTML standards are not applicable (unless OP is working with SVG).

Comment: Have you tried '#0000FF7F' ? i.e., hex #RRGGBBAA

Comment: The `#RRGGBBAA`/`#RGBA` notation is already available in some browsers (Firefox 49 beta and Chrome 52), but unlikely currently supported by ImageMagick. You could write a conversion function yourself.

Answer (score 1):

you can use "[dechex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php)" to get an hexadecimal representation of the given unsigned number.

Comment: I don't understand, I already have the hexadecimal representation, but I need to add transparency and I don't know how to do this

Comment: Sorry I misunderstand. You cannot insert alpha values in this way. You must use rgba or CSS opacity property